# disable a JS depending of my media queries

Tags: ios, css, media-queries, javascript

I'm using a JS script on my website (on wordpress) to get a stick to top header when scrolling.
I'm now working on my media queries for mobile and ipad because there are some issues...

I would like to desable this JS on mobile and ipad so that my header stays relative.
I can't find a way to do it,
anyone can help ?

here is my JS code :

```
$(function () {
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() === stickyHeaderTop+1) {
            $('#stickyheader').hide();
            console.log('p');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#stickyheader').fadeIn(500).css('position','fixed');
            $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
            var mT = $('#stickyheader').css('height');
            $('#stickyheader').next('.post').css('marginTop', mT);
        }else{
            $('#stickyheader').css({
                position: 'relative',
            });
            $('#stickyheader').next('.post').css('marginTop', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

and my css :

```
#header {background-color: #f8f8f8;top: 0;padding-top: 20px;}
#stickyheader { width: 100%;padding-top:10px;top: 0;z-index: 1000;padding-bottom: 10px;line-height: 24px;position:relative;background-color: #f8f8f8;}
#unstickyheader {height:auto;}
```

my media queries css :

```
/* Media queries!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*IPAD*/

@media screen and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

}

/*IPHONE*/
@media screen  and (max-device-width : 568px) and (min-device-width : 320px)   {
#menu-menu {list-style:none;font-size: 35px;font-weight: 700}
}
```

and finaly a JS fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/64Dde/

thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 0):

This might be your answer: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

CSS media queries for JavaScript.

Example as it relates to your code:

```
if (matchMedia("media query here").matches) {
    window.onscroll = ...
}
```

Comment: thanks @Greg Burghardt, I thought there was an easyer way to do it... I'm still searching

Comment: thanks @Greg Burghardt... I'm trying to complete the JS code you gave me... 

    if (matchMedia("@media screen  and(max-device-width : 568px) and (min-device-width : 320px)").matches) {
}
is this correct ? it doesn't seem to work